# How to replace a default video player in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, video, vlc

For example with vlc or any other good player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

Then start it up, and select `File Type Manager` from the sidebar. Select the `Video` category, and then click on the first row under `File Type` and scroll down and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click on the last row to select all the different video formats. Click the `Edit` button and select your preferred video player from the list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your Software Centre links don't work because Ubuntu Tweak is not in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @alfalive @fluteflute My bad, I thought it was in the repositories, updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

- Right Click on the file you want to play.
- Properties > Open With > VLC Media Player (say).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install VLC,to install VLC on your system just run the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c-korn/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

**To replace default video player,**

Open nautilus, right click on file you which to change default app,choose **Properties** from the menu.Go to the tab **Open With** and choose the player you prefer or Add.

Comment: Thanks but that only install vlc and do not replace a default player. Should I simply delete it?

Comment: Hmm this doesn't install vlc 1.1 this install 1.0.6